# Does FTB accept amended tax returns over Fax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, california, amended-tax-return

So I sent Letter of Explanation over regular mail to Franchise Tax Board. I called them and they claim not to have yet received and/or scanned it. And instead suggested to Fax it.

However, I could not find fax number on their website so I tried to contact them over chat to find if it is ok to fax Tax Return. Now I got different answer that it is not ok to electronically send it because this is for previous years.

Contradicting information!

**Has anyone had successful experience with sending amended Tax Returns to Franchise Tax Board?**

This is for General Partnership form 565.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CA tax returns must be submitted in paper by mail, or through e-file. Fax is not an option. Amended forms must be filed on paper, if I remember correctly.

[More details here](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/individuals/Filing_Information.shtml?WT.mc_id=Forms_FilingHelp_FileInfo).

Letters you can fax, yes. Make sure you get the correct fax number and call to confirm they got it.

But better send *certified* mail, as well.